# Internet explorer 9 (8 ?) iframe doesn't show up after removing display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, iframe

If i put iframe with google maps without "display:none" it shows up correctly, but when i add display:none in css class and then i remove it with jquery, the iframe with map doesnt show up.

HTML:

```
<div id="kontakt_siedziba">

        <iframe id="mapa_siedziba" class="hidden" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d10163.095243410511!2d16.666852538623033!3d50.44531365108525!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x3d08e591f3fac383!2sJatax+Sp.+z+o.o.!5e0!3m2!1spl!2spl!4v1466029556470" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
  iframe#mapa_siedziba {
                float: right;
            }

    .hidden {
                display: none;
            }

#kontakt_siedziba, #kontakt_baza {
            height: 140px;
            border: 0px solid #007fff;
            border-radius: 5px;
            transition: padding 1s;
        }

.unfolded_map {
            padding: 20px;

        }
```

Script:

```
<script>

    var clicked=0;
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#siedziba").click(function(){
            if(clicked==0){

            $("#kontakt_siedziba").addClass("unfolded_map").animate(
                {height: '300px',borderWidth: '4'},
                function(){ $("#mapa_siedziba").fadeIn(500, function(){
                    clicked=1;

                }); } );

            }else if(clicked==1){

                $("#mapa_siedziba").fadeOut(1000, function(){

                    $("#kontakt_siedziba").animate(
                        {height: '140px',borderWidth: '0'},
                        function()
                        {
                            clicked=0;
                        }).removeClass("unfolded_map") ;

                });

            } 
        });

    });
</script>
```

I tried also removeClass instead of fade in, but it's not working either

Comment: Maybe try an alternative way of hiding it instead of `display:none`. https://www.sitepoint.com/five-ways-to-hide-elements-in-css/

Answer (score 1):

You can try two ways:

1. Wrapping the iframe into a div and hiding/unhiding the div
2. Removing the iframe dom element and readding it

Example

```
var detachedItem = $('#mapa_siedziba').detach();
setTimeout(function() {
   $("#open_menu").click(function()  {
      $("#kontakt_siedziba").append($detachedItem);
   });
}, 4);
```

Comment: 1. Nope, it still doesn't work :/ 2. I dont understand, what do you mean ?

Comment: instead of hiding it you can try removing it from the dom and readding

Comment: How to achieve that ? Using php to add or remove whole iframe line ?

Comment: I have added and example

Comment: "enter code here" - am i supposed to paste whole iframe here ? I also added a button with id="open_menu" to just test it, but it doesn't do anything. I assume that i'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: Sorry It was a wrong copy paste. Try now executing the code.

Comment: It doesn't work in any browser. I deleted ".hidden" class and pasted your script in place of mine. Without your script map is present, but when i paste your script map doesn't show up (thats ok) but when i click button "open_menu" it does nothing. Map still doesn't show up :/